# React child node height not correct

Tags: reactjs

I have two component `Articles` and `Article`. Articles will send an ajax call and rerender Article list after complete.

When trying to get each Article's height in `componentDidMount`, it sometimes returns incorrect height of the `Article` node. But it returns correct value in other method. Is there a way to get the correct height in Article's `componentDidMount` ?

```
// Articles component
 var Articles = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      articles: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax(api_url)
      .done(function(data) {
        if(this.isMounted()) {
          this.setState({
            articles: data.posts,
        });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    var articles = this.state.articles.map(function(article, index) {
      return <Article key={article.id} article={article} index={index} />
    });

    return (
      <div className="articles">
        {articles}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

// Article component
var Article = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    article: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      height: 0
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var node;

    node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(node.offsetHeight); // incorrect value
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    var node;

    node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(node.offsetHeight); // correct value
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="article">
        <header className="intro-header">
          {this.setBanner()}
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div className="post-heading">
                            <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>

                            <span className="meta">Posted by {this.props.article.author.name} on {this.props.article.date}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <article>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.article.content}}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't expect the `offsetHeight` to be wrong on `componentDidMount`.  Is there more code that you aren't showing?  What does the `render` method of `Article` look like?

Comment: Edit for the render mothod of  `Article`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have images without express height attributes inside the articles? I've experienced this issue before and that was the cause.

If so it is likely due to the images not having loaded on componentDidMount (which is highly likely to happen) and could be resolved by either adding an express width and height to the images or, if that is not possible, deferring initial measurement until images have loaded with something like https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the height value return correctly after image loaded. But I have some videos are not supported by this plugin. Is there other solutions to resolve both images and videos?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get parent's `offsetHeight` in child `componentDidMount`, you'll get `undefined`.

```
The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html